# How to redirect in react.js after handling an error

Tags: reactjs, redirect, routes

Im building a simple app where I want there to be a redirect to the root when there is an error.
The error is working fine.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const { name, room } = quertString.parse(location.search);

    socket = io(ENDPOINT);
 
    setUserName(name);
    setRoomID(room);

    socket.emit('join', { name, room }, (error) => {
      if(error) {
        alert(error)
      }
      return <Redirect to="./"/>
    });
  }, [ENDPOINT, location.search ]);
```

what would be the best way for me to do this?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use the history from props router

```
const Component = ({history}) => {
```

then

```
useEffect(() => {
    const { name, room } = quertString.parse(location.search);

    socket = io(ENDPOINT);

    setUserName(name);
    setRoomID(room);

    socket.emit('join', { name, room }, (error) => {
      if(error) {
        alert(error)
      }
      history.push("/")
    });
  }, [ENDPOINT, location.search ]);
```